# How to automatically take a picture using SMS string as input

Tags: android, text, automation

I was wondering if someone could help me with study material or idea on how to automatically take a picture using an input string from an SMS on android application,same case as of Whatsapp activation mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a background android service separately or within your app(waiting for activation). It will be monitoring and analyzing sms from one or more numbers. If the sms contains the expected valid string this service will activate the camera. This service will need some permission to preform these task i.e Permission to activate camera, permission to read contacts, permission to monitor sms.
You can look at the following links for help:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html